# Where is my vim installed?

Tags: installing

My vim was installed on debian8 with the apt-get command.

```
apt-get install vim
$ find / -name 'autoload'
/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload
$ find  /  -name  '.vim'
```

The above command can find nothing.

```
$ ls  /etc/vim
vimrc  vimrc.tiny
```

Is my vim installed on  /usr/share/vim  properly?

Comment: Well, how did you install it? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: apt-get install vim

Comment: To locate the executable you can use `which vim` but muru is right when he asks what problem are you trying to solve. You should edit your question and give more details about that.

Comment: `dpkg -L vim | grep bin`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt On ubuntu at least `apt` and `dpkg` don't install vim in a single package "vim", its organised as mulitple dependency packages, so `dpkg -L vim` isn't necessarily going to be useful. e.g. for `vim-gtk` it doesn't even mention where the `$VIMRUNTIME` is at all

Comment: @the_velour_fog  He did `apt-get install vim`. So he can see what is installed with the provided command. And yes, on Ubuntu there exists a basic package vim. See `apt-cache show vim` Yes there are other vim flavor packages. Then one should check which package was installed and can use that package name instead of vim in the above command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Where is my vim installed?

If you installed through `apt` the following sequence should get you to the Vim installation.

From inside Vim,

```
:echo $VIMRUNTIME
/usr/share/vim/vim74
```

You could look in here and you would discover the Vim files, but if you wanted a more programmatic, portable approach, you could then use `dpkg` i.e.

- `dpkg -S, -- search for file owner`:
  this tells you which `.deb` package/s are responsible for the path `/usr/share/vim/vim74`.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/vim/vim74
vim-tiny, vim-runtime, vim-common: /usr/share/vim/vim7
```

These are the packages, so you can use `dpkg --list-files` to tell you where all the files belonging to the packages are.  For example, if you run

```
dpkg --list-files vim-runtime
```

you'll get a dump of file names, which will tell you where the bulk of the vim installation is.
You'll see that on Debian and Ubuntu, most of Vim's files are in `/usr/share/`. <sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>folder for architecture independent files as per the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).</sup>

Comment: What makes you say the fhs isn't followed on Debian and Ubuntu Vim?

Comment: @muru I mis-spoke. My first impression after seeing  the bulk of the files were in `/usr/share/vim/vim74`  in a "monolithic"  configuration - was they weren't following FHS. But I guess because vim's code is architecture independent? its following FHS after all? I have edited answer as I dont actually know that answer to that.

Answer (score 8):

You are not supposed to do anything with the default runtime so where Vim was installed doesn't matter.

Whatever customization you want to do, do it in `$HOME`.

Comment: While the original question didn't give specifics, there's a lot of reasons why one might want to find the installed location. For instance, perhaps you want to grab a syntax or colors file as a template for a new one. Placing custom versions of those files should, as you comment, probably be done in `$HOME`, but finding the system install directory is a legitimate request. The other answer of `:echo $VIMRUNTIME` is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

[apt-file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/apt-file.1.html) can do it. To install use:

```
apt-get install apt-file
```

Then use the following:

```
apt-file list vim
```

[apt-file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/apt-file.1.html) lists file names in all packages, whether they are installed or not.