# Where is the .vim folder by default in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux-ubuntu

I have seen that the `.vim` directory is in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/`, but it isn't. The closest I can find is `/etc/vim/`, but that does not contain what I need (namely, `init.vim`). Am I missing something?

I am running Vim 8.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.2 x86_64.

Comment: @BLayer neither of those exist either.

Comment: Okay...I give up. LOL. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE, BTW!

Comment: Wait...are you looking for  your personal vimrc or system vimrc? System stuff is often  in `/usr/share/vim*`... personal vimrc you create yourself. Also, start vim and do `:echo $VIMRUNTIME $MYVIMRC` AND `:version` ... with all that you should have everything you need.

Comment: @BLayer I don't exactly know. I am trying to set up [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim), and it just said to edit `init.vim` in `.vim` in the installation guide. This is my first time messing with vim.

Comment: That's probably referring to neovim....but it also works with Vim 8 so you just need to find your vimrc...my last comment should get you there..

Comment: If you haven't created it then it doesn't exist (yet). BTW. Setting up plugins while you're still learning basic stuff is particularly bad idea.

Comment: Agree with Matt. I mentioned that you need to create your personal vimrc yourself. `:version` shows the order that system and personal (or "user") vimrcs are searched in.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Strongly related: [1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/6785/10604), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238492/301073). In particular, it sounds like you should read `:help startup`, `:help vimrc-intro`, and that you likely need to create the right directories/files.

Comment: Okay, that was quite a flurry of activity. :) Do you think you have everything you need now?

Comment: @BLayer not quite. I have it installed, and vim says it has loaded with :scriptnames, but it does not actually *work*.

Comment: You mean vimrc (not deoplete)? In that case please update your question with details i.e. where you put the file, its name, what you put in it, what you checked for...anything you think might be a pertinent detail.

Comment: But start by reading those help sections from DBK if you haven't already! Could be the answer is in there.

Answer (score 2):

Vim/Neovim config file/directory must be created manually.

For Neovim the default location is `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`, unless you have custom `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` set.

For Vim it's either `~/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`.

In any case exact rules are described under `:h $MYVIMRC` topic of the help system.